# how to make user login from only one device only one login android firebase

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, firebase-authentication

I want that from a Device An user Can only create an account. or If an user tries To login an Old account to a new device He can't.

Comment: You mean you want to bind a single user to a single device?

Comment: @dan-baruch Yes

Comment: Well, I can't offer code because I haven't worked with fireBase and I have no clue how you built your code, but you can simply add another field to the users table including the device unique id, IMEI, Serial, Mac, what ever you can access that is unique and when ever a user wants to log in, that ID must match what's written on the table

Comment: @dan-baruch Thanking you for your replay. IMEI, Serial, Mac this are risky way. if you know any others unique id which never be changed then please suggest me.

Comment: Why are IMEI and Serial risky? They can only be changed if the device is physically opened and tempered with. You can also simply save it in your app's data. Something like this: OnCreate you create a uniqueID based on either a key / timestamp / anything that you find valid enough and save it in sharedPrefrences. That way, the app will have access to it and other devices wont. Do note though, if the user clears app's data or uninstalls and then reinstalls the app he will not be able to enter the same user again as the ID saved in SharedPreferences will be deleted along with the app

Comment: Can you explain how to get IMEI number etc.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234846/discussion-between-kumar-santanu-and-dan-baruch).

Answer (score 0):

```
private String android_id = Secure.getString(getContext().getContentResolver(),
                                                    Secure.ANDROID_ID);
```

Just you get unique id from android hardware,now you can save and check hardwareid in backend.

Comment: Yes Dude @KumarSantanu

Comment: This value is not final, it can change. See doc here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure#ANDROID_ID

Comment: @JonZarate Please suggest me any final value who never changed.